# cannot access local variable 'image' where it is not associated with value in python

Tags: python

hello everyone i am working on a project about puzzle game. I had problem with uploading image to program by using tk.filedialog but i have this error

UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'image' where it is not associated with a value

here is my code:

```
def select_image():
    file_path = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if file_path:
        # Resmi 16 parçaya böl
        image = image.open(file_path)
        image = image.resize((400, 400))
        image_list = []
        for i in range(0, 400, 100):
            for j in range(0, 400, 100):
                piece = image.crop((i, j, i+100, j+100))
                image_list.append(piece)
```

Comment: `image.open()` makes no sense - you're only just defining `image` in that line of code, you can't use it to define itself!  I think that should be `Image.open()`, referring to a class from the PIL or Pillow library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mistake here, to open an image by using `tk.filedialog` you need to use something like `PIL.Image` (
it seems you have mistaken it for image, which has the same name as your variable, so it is reported that image has been used even though undeclared). Change the code to:

```py
from PIL import Image

...
image = Image.open(file_path)
...
```

Comment: i wanna resize the image but i have this error

AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'resize'

Comment: [It](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-image-resize-method/) can help you.